# Get attribute from item on JavaFx TableView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a table to list orders.
If i want to bind a table column with a property of the order, i do it like this:

```
<TableColumn prefWidth="361.0" text="Name">
    <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="person" />
    </cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

But if i want to bind it with an attribute from this property? I have tried to do it like this, but id didn't work:

```
<TableColumn prefWidth="361.0" text="Name">
    <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="person.age" />
    </cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

How to do it?

This is my model class:

```
public class Order{
   private Integer number;
   private Date date;
   private Person person;
   //getters and setters...
}
```

and this is the Person class:

```
public class Person{
   private String name;
   private Integer age;
   //getters and setters...
}
```

Comment: How is the first example, that you have given, working ?

Comment: You must try something like `<PropertyValueFactory property="age" />`

Comment: Show your model class (i.e. the class representing each row in the table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the cell factory directly in FXML here, unless you go to the trouble of making your own class implementing the appropriate `Callback`.

Instead, set the cell factory in the controller:

```
<TableColumn prefWidth="361.0" text="Name" fx:id="ageColumn"/>
```

and in the controller:

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Order, Integer> ageColumn ;

    public void initialize() {
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory( data -> {
             Order order = data.getValue();
             Person person = order.getPerson();
             Integer age = person.getAge();
             return new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(age);
        });

        //...
   }
 );
```

Comment: I just set the cellFactory through FXML because it's easy to read and it is a better MVC approach than doing that on the controller. But i will sure use your method to solve my problem, as there is no more methods but changing my model, which i don't want to do. Thanks